# How to write a string in replace of a number in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to categorise the years based on some conditions. If any year has rainfall less than a specific number it will indicate as a dry year. I have tried the following, but it gives me error "In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same."

The code is

```
Year_Category = zeros(ny,1);
for i = 1:ny;
    if (xy(i)< Lower_Limit)
        Year_Category(i) = 'Dry';
    elseif (xy(i)> Upper_Limit)
        Year_Category(i) = 'Wet';
    else
        Year_Category(i) = 'Average';
    end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign characters to a numeric array.  That's why you're getting a dimension mismatch.  Each character is a single slot and you can't do that in this case.  Use cell arrays instead:

```
Year_Category = cell(ny,1); %// Change
for i = 1:ny;
    if (xy(i)< Lower_Limit)
        Year_Category{i} = 'Dry'; %// Change
    elseif (xy(i)> Upper_Limit)
        Year_Category{i} = 'Wet'; %// Change
    else
        Year_Category{i} = 'Average'; %// Change
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you rayryeng; it worked but it give me answer as a cell. But I would like to have the results as an array (double). When i have tried to convert cell into double (Year_Category_M = str2double(Year_Category); ) it shows all the values as NaN.

Comment: That's not possible.  You are trying to assign characters to a `double` array.  That's why I suggested a cell instead.  This can work if you change `Dry`, `Wet` and `Average` to actual numbers instead... like 0, 1, or 2.  You can't do this using characters.